# Passing form values through URL to another page using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently stuck in this form. What I am trying to do is enter the name and email from the form and redirect the values on another page but the values should be shown in the address bar on the next page and the point is this should be done only within JavaScript.

**Here is the form look:** 
[image]

values would be shown like this:
[image]
 where **xxxxx** is **name** or **email**.

**code for the form:**

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/gNucJF" id="redirect_984cda7485160f2afcf0ac36e7276fca" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_redirect_onlist" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/gNucJF"/>
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="My_Web_Form_2" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name (awf_first),name (awf_last),email" />

<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-96665553-first">First Name:</label>
<input id="awf_field-96665553-first" type="text" class="text" name="name (awf_first)" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="500" />

<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-96665553-last">Last Name:</label>
<input id="awf_field-96665553-last" class="text" type="text" name="name (awf_last)" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="501" />

<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-96665554">Email: </label>
<input class="text" id="awf_field-96665554" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="502" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " />

<input name="submit" onclick="HandleSubmit()" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="503" />
<div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center"><p>We respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.aweber.com/permission.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></p>


 </form>
```

**here is what I have done:**

```
   function HandleSubmit() {
    var baseUrl = "https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/gNucJF?";
    baseUrl += "name=" + document.getElementById("awf_field-96665553-first").value +"&email="+  document.getElementById("awf_field-96665554").value;


    window.location.href = baseUrl; 
     }
```

Now, when I enter the values in Name and email fields and hit the submit button I will redirect to the next page.
**Address bar of next page:**
[image]

nothing happened!

What I want is if I enter name=navjot in form then URL bar will contain https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/gNucJF?name=navjot I know it's a simple but I don’t know how to do in javascript any help is appreciated any help or example would help me.

Comment: As your element are wrapped in `<FORM>`, it is submitted when the button is clicked. So either remove `<form>` element or use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: Omy god sir you are great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: itsss workked!!!!!!!!